# Display the latest news separately from other

Tags: python, django

I want to display the latest news on one page separately and all the rest below, but I don't know how this can be done.

`views.py`

```
class PostsView(ListView):
model = Post
queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by('-date')
template_name = 'post/posts.html'
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostsView.as_view()),
    path('<int:pk>', views.PostView.as_view()),
    path('add/', views.PostFormView.as_view(), name='add'),
]
```

Comment: Well, why just don't write two querysets, one to query for the last post, and the other to query for all posts?

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment, you can create two querysets.
like this:

For all posts:

```
queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by('-date')
```

For latest posts:

```
queryset2 = queryset[:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have it on separate pages, you have to have two separate views and urls, e.g.:

All the news:

```
class PostsViewAll(ListView):
    model = Post
    queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    template_name = 'post/posts_all.html'
```

The latest news:

```
class PostsViewLatest(ListView):
    model = Post
    queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by('-date')[:5]
    template_name = 'post/posts_latest.html'
```

And separate urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('all', views.PostViewAll.as_view()),
    path('latest/', views.PostViewLatest.as_view()),
]
```

Or if you want to have it on the same page, you have just one view and url, and you can overwrite `get_context_data` to get different querysets.